# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. LARAVEL ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I wanted to make a basic *login/logout* in Laravel. So I created a new folder under `resources/views` called **auth** and then I made a new file `login.blade.php` inserted this into it:

```
   <html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" size="40"><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" size="40"><br><br>
<input hidden name="_token" value="{{csrf_token}}">
<input type="submit" value="send"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After that I edited the web.php like this:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); });

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('welcome'); });

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('auth.login'); });

Route::post('/login','Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::post('/logout','Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

So it should work fine because everything makes sense but whenever I goto login url, I see this error message:

**ErrorException in 6c95db2d362954448afd30aa9a2bf2cb0fc31937.php line 6:
Use of undefined constant csrf_token - assumed 'csrf_token' (View: G:\xampp\htdocs\o2architect\root\laravel\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)**

So can anyone tell me whats going on here ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it:

```
<input hidden name="_token" value="{{csrf_token}}">
```

to

```
<input hidden name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, Hope this work for you!

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" size="40"><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" size="40"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="submit" value="send"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **csrf_token** is a helper function of Laravel so you will have to call it with parentheses.

Just Change

```
<input hidden name="_token" value="{{csrf_token}}">
```

to

```
<input hidden name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Recommendation

You can use `{!! csrf_field() !!}` which will create hidden input field with the CSRF Token.

In the code above the form that you have shown is a GET Request form, you will have to change it to `action="POST"` and `GET` request forms work without CSRF Token also.